# How to disable google Smart Lock when running tests on firebase test lab?

Tags: android, firebase, android-instrumentation, firebase-test-lab, google-smartlockpasswords

I'm trying to give firebase test lab a spin before deciding to go all in. The application needs sign in credentials and has Smart Lock integration. Since Smart Lock is enabled on firebase test lab devices it gets in the way when entering credentials.

So is there any way of disabling it?

Comment: Hi Bruno, Smart Lock is supposed to be disabled on Firebase Test Lab devices. Could you either contact FTL support or join #test-lab in the community Slack channel at https://firebase.community/ so that we can help debug?